# How to set dateFormat option to jQuery datepicker, when called onClick?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onclick

I have an input field which is created with .append dynamically, so this means i have to call the datepicker by adding onClick function to the field. It looks like this:

```
<input class="myclass" name="myfield" type="text" id="myfield" onclick="$(\'#myfield\').datepicker();$(\'#myfield\').datepicker(\'show\');">
```

**What is the correct way to add the [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) option inside this function?**

I tried:

```
<input class="myclass" name="myfield" type="text" id="myfield" onclick="$(\'#myfield\').datepicker();$(\'#myfield\').datepicker(\'"show", "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd"\');">
```

But i get `ILLEGAL`

Answer (score 1):

After doing some digging i found my answer. Here the demo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input  name="puDate1" type="text" id="puDate1" onclick="$(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd' }).datepicker('show');" placeholder="Date" >
```